# Symmetric matrix and power of two

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is my first post.

Given an square matrix $n\times n$, such that the elements on the main diagonal are 1, each row an each column has exact one time a number in $\{1,2,...,n\}$, the first column and first row are $(1,2,3,...,n)$, and if $a_{r,s}=a_{u,v}$, then $a_{u,s}=a_{r,v}$, how to prove that $n$ is a power of two?

I have already shown that the matrix is symmetric, but i don't know how to conclude. Any hint is wellcome.

For example, matrix

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&2&3&4\\2&1&4&3\\3&4&1&2\\4&3&2&1\end{array}\right]$ satisfies all the above conditions.

Comment: Where did you see that $n$ is a power of 2?

Comment: @mathematician42 your matrix is wrong: $a_{2,1}=a_{3,2}$, but $a_{3,1}\neq a_{2,2}$.

Comment: @gerryMyerson, that is what i want to show. In example, $n=2^2$

Comment: Yes, I misread your question, I deleted that comment.

Comment: Didn't find it yet, but you can inductively construct $2^n$-matrices that satisfy these properties. The fact that the matrix is symmetric tells you that you can ignore the lower half of your matrix. The condition $a_{r,s}=a_{u,v}\Rightarrow a_{u,s}=a_{r,v}$ induces a pairing of elements and any element can be paired to some element in the first row. This should be useful, but I do not know how yet.

Comment: My question is, you state it as if you already know somehow that $n$ must be a power of 2. Do you already know that? Did you see it stated somewhere that $n$ must be a power of 2?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is a part of the statement

Comment: OK. So, where did you first see the statement? (I feel like I'm pulling teeth here)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.